# Как удалить одну вкладку из TabHost?

Tags: android, java

Я нашел (на SO) решение, как удалить все вкладки. А как удалить одну, зная её индекс? Казалось бы, очевидно, но у меня не получается. Не могли бы вы объяснить это по-русски.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TabHost Remove Tab problem](http://www.coderanch.com/t/460859/Android/Mobile/TabHost-Remove-Tab)

Comment: Это всё из-за этой строчки:

    myTabHost.setCurrentTab(0); //IMPORTANT 

Я её пропустил!

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно меняю свойство **setVisibility**:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```